# .NET Core 3.0: Razor views don't automatically recompile on change

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-3.0

According to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-compilation?view=aspnetcore-3.0), Razor views should, by default, recompile on change on local environments for ASP.NET Core 3.0.

However, my project doesn't do this locally. If I change a view and refresh when I'm debugging locally, the change is not reflected. I have to stop the solution, re-run, and then see the change.

I am doing this on a default ASP.NET Core Web Application template on Visual Studio 2019 with ASP.NET Core 3.0.0 Preview 2 using Razor pages. Any idea if I need to change settings to enable this feature?

Comment: .cshtml razor views do get recompiled. Can you double check? Try adding a <h1>Test</h1>. Start the app, load the page. you should see "Test". Then change this to <h1>Foo</h1>. You should see "Foo".

Comment: Doesn't work! I have to stop and start the solution. Captured it here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xOWQK2SvE2dskSYRdLz9X7iEmAv7BcTN/view?usp=sharing - Have tried on multiple machines with the stock Razor Pages template.

Comment: Are you running a on mac or pc or linux?

Also, it might be an issue with the preview. Can you try using asp.net core 2.x?

Comment: PC, Visual Studio 2019 preview. I tried with 2.2 and it works! So there's something that changed in 3.0.

Comment: I am on a fully updated .net core 3/VS and had to add `.AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();` Thank you!

Answer (score 69, accepted):

OK it looks like it's not supported yet :(

> Runtime compilation removed As a consequence of cleaning up the
>   ASP.NET Core shared framework to not depend on Roslyn, support for
>   runtime compilation of pages and views has also been removed in this
>   preview release. Instead compilation of pages and views is performed
>   at build time. In a future preview update we will provide a NuGet
>   packages for optionally enabling runtime compilation support in an
>   app.

You can read more about the issue here https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/343

Applications that require runtime compilation or re-compilation of Razor files should:

- Add a reference to the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation` package. It'll be available as part of the **3.0.0-preview3** release.
- Update the application's `ConfigureServices` to include a call to `AddMvcRazorRuntimeCompilation`:

Comment: `AddMvcRazorRuntimeCompilation` is `AddRazorRuntimeCompilation` with ASP.Net Core 3.0 Preview 4

Comment: I'm using .NET Core 6 and it worked for me in all of projects.

Answer (score 77):

For ASP.NET Core 3 release version:

```
   services.AddControllersWithViews().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-compilation?view=aspnetcore-3.0

It can also be enabled conditionally only for local development, quoted from the link:

> Runtime compilation can be enabled such that it's only available for
> local development. Conditionally enabling in this manner ensures that
> the published output:
>
> Uses compiled views.
> Is smaller in size.
> Doesn't enable file watchers
> in production.

```
   public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
        Env = env;
    }

    public IWebHostEnvironment Env { get; set; }
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        IMvcBuilder builder = services.AddRazorPages();

#if DEBUG
            if (Env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                builder.AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
            }
#endif
    }
```

Comment: Tip about versions of the nuget package related to .Net core version. In case you use .Net Core 3.0, you cannot select the later versions of this Nuget package. But version 3.0.0 of the Nuget lib works with .Net Core 3.0. If you use .Net Core 3.1, you can select newer versions.

Answer (score 43):

To get runtime view compilation back in `ASP.NET Core` 3

1. Reference `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation`
2. Call `services.AddMvc().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation()`
3. Remove `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design` if there's a version mismatch on the `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common` package

Comment: Just a hint for others: when using Nuget, tick/check the "pre-release" box.

Comment: Is there a way to prevent the assets from being deployed to production?  I tried some combinations of PrivateAssets on the PackageReference but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: In Core 2.2 razor options has FileProviders and it works even without any recompilation. Just edit cshtml and voila. In core 3 this property is removed. :(

https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/14572

Comment: +1 because removing the Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design package was the secret sauce that nowhere else mentions.

Comment: @tkburbidge I just ran into that issue with the package, too. Oddly enough, I had two lines that were exactly the same, back-to-back. I removed both, and could compile. **Even more oddly**, I then put the lines back in place, and was still able to compile.

Answer (score 28):

Runtime compilation is enabled using the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation` package. To enable runtime compilation, apps must:

1. Install the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation` NuGet
   package.
2. Update the project's `Startup.ConfigureServices` method to include a
   call to `AddRazorRuntimeCompilation`:

```
services
    .AddControllersWithViews()
    .AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-compilation?view=aspnetcore-3.0

Answer (score 20):

To get runtime Razor Views Compilation back in ASP.NET Core 3.1:

1. Install the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation` NuGet package.
2. Update the project's `Startup.ConfigureServices` method to include a call to `AddRazorRuntimeCompilation`.
3. `services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation()`;

   [Razor file compilation in ASP.NET Core 3.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-compilation?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Answer (score 16):

Step 1: Install the below package from NuGet Package Manager for Solution.

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation

[image]

Step 2: Add the below code in ConfigureServices of Startup.cs file

services.AddControllersWithViews().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();

[image]

Save the page and then refresh the client browser.

If you are using Razor then add the code for services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();

Answer (score 13):

In .NET Core 3.1, you need disable generation of the `views.dll` file.

1. Add the below code to your `.csproj` file (in the root of your project):

   ```xml
   <PropertyGroup>
       <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
       <UserSecretsId>...</UserSecretsId>

       <!-- add from this line: -->
       <CopyRazorGenerateFilesToPublishDirectory>true</CopyRazorGenerateFilesToPublishDirectory>
       <CopyRefAssembliesToPublishDirectory>false</CopyRefAssembliesToPublishDirectory>
       <MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>false</MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>
       <RazorCompileOnBuild>false</RazorCompileOnBuild>
       <!-- to this line. -->

   </PropertyGroup>
   ```
2. Install the below package from the NuGet Package Manager for the Solution.

   ```cs
   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation
   ```
3. Add the below code to the `ConfigureServices` method of your `Startup.cs` file:

   ```cs
   services.AddMvc().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
   ```

   Or

   ```cs
   services.AddControllersWithViews().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
   ```

   Or

   ```cs
   services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
   ```

After this, publish again and run it. It will work.

Comment: For my .NET 5.0 only the following tags were needed inside .csproj

`<RazorCompileOnBuild>false</RazorCompileOnBuild>
    <RazorCompileOnPublish>false</RazorCompileOnPublish>
    <CopyRefAssembliesToPublishDirectory>false</CopyRefAssembliesToPublishDirectory>`

All other 2 & 3 steps also needed

Comment: Same as @Nathan for Razor Class Library with NetCore 6

Answer (score 7):

Simpliest way to configure Runtime Compilation for Local Development only is to update launch profiles in `launchSettings.json`. This method requires no code changes to configure a project which is running locally (it will not affect your production).

See [the official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-compilation?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#conditionally-enable-runtime-compilation-in-an-existing-project):

> 1. Install the **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation** NuGet package.
> 2. Modify the launch profile environmentVariables section in launchSettings.json:
>
>    - Verify `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` is set to "Development".
>    - Set `ASPNETCORE_HOSTINGSTARTUPASSEMBLIES` to "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation".

Example:

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:57676",
      "sslPort": 44364
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
        "ASPNETCORE_HOSTINGSTARTUPASSEMBLIES": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation"
      }
    },
    "RazorPagesApp": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
        "ASPNETCORE_HOSTINGSTARTUPASSEMBLIES": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Just an added note -- you may want to only conditionally enable this runtime compilation, so that the published output:

- Uses compiled views.
- Is smaller in size.
- Doesn't enable file watchers in production.

[Conditionally enable runtime compilation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-compilation?view=aspnetcore-3.0#conditionally-enable-runtime-compilation)