# Cannot find Index.cshtml NET Core App 3.0

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, kestrel-http-server

Yes, there are loads of questions and answers on this but I can't find one that works for me - I just can't see what I'm missing, or doing wrong.

Windows desktop app that just needs to serve a couple of Razor pages (along with SignalR). If I browse to https://localhost:5000 with V1 of the HomeController (see below) then the browser correctly displays the string, so I know I'm browsing to the correct URI. But if I change the controller to return the view instead, I get the following:

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
InvalidOperationException: The view 'Index' was not found. The following locations were searched:
/Views/Home/Index.cshtml
/Views/Shared/Index.cshtml
/Pages/Shared/Index.cshtml

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewEngines.ViewEngineResult.EnsureSuccessful(IEnumerable<string> originalLocations)
```

When running the latter, the output window displays:

```
Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime: Information: Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime: Information: Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime: Information: Hosting environment: Development
Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime: Information: Content root path: C:\Users\geoff\source\repos\xxx\yyy\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.0
```

Index.cshtml (in that casing) is located at (also under wwwroot\Views etc):

```
C:\Users\geoff\source\repos\xxx\yyy\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.0\Views\Home\Index.cshtml
```

Index.cshtml is set to BuildAction: Content and CopyToOutput: CopyIfNewer, and yes, the file is there when running with the correct casing.

I have read something about adding a view engine but my understanding is the Razor one is there anyway. I *think* that's the only thing I haven't tried. I also tried custom routes instead of the default, with no success.

Help greatly appreciated.

Part of .csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
    <PreserveCompilationContext />
    <MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>true</MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>
    <MvcRazorExcludeViewFilesFromPublish>false</MvcRazorExcludeViewFilesFromPublish>
    <MvcRazorExcludeRefAssembliesFromPublish>false</MvcRazorExcludeRefAssembliesFromPublish>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Remove="Views\Home\Index.cshtml" />
    <None Remove="wwwroot\Views\Home\Index.cshtml" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="Views\Home\Index.cshtml">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="wwwroot\Views\Home\Index.cshtml">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.ViewCompilation" Version="1.1.0">
      <PrivateAssets>All</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="wwwroot\**\*;**.cshtml">
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="AvalonEdit" Version="5.0.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" Version="5.2.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" Version="3.0.0-preview3-19153-02" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http" Version="2.2.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.JsonPatch" Version="3.0.0-preview5-19227-01" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Core" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions" Version="2.2.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

App.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    private IHost _host;

    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
        _host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(e.Args)
            .UseContentRoot(path)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webHostBuilder => webHostBuilder.UseStartup<StartUp>())
            .ConfigureServices(services =>
            {
                services.AddTransient<MainWindow>();

                services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder =>
                {
                    builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                           .AllowAnyMethod()
                           .AllowAnyHeader();
                }));

                services.AddMvc();

                services.AddSignalR().AddHubOptions<SsoHub>(options =>
                {
                    options.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
                });

                services.AddSingleton<ISsoHubHelper, SsoHubHelper>();

            })
            .Build();

        _host.Start();
    }

    protected override void OnExit(ExitEventArgs e) => _host.Dispose();
}
```

Part of startup.cs:

```
public class StartUp
{
    public static IServiceProvider ServiceProvider { get; private set; }
    public static T GetService<T>() { return ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<T>(); }

    public static ISsoHubHelper HubContext;

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        app.UseCors(builder =>
        {
            builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                   .AllowAnyMethod()
                   .AllowAnyHeader();
        });

        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseStatusCodePages();
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();

        app.UseSignalR((configure) =>
        {
            var desiredTransports =
                HttpTransportType.WebSockets |
                HttpTransportType.LongPolling;

            configure.MapHub<SsoHub>("/ssohub", (options) =>
            {
                options.Transports = desiredTransports;
            });
        });

        ServiceProvider = serviceProvider;
        HubContext = GetService<ISsoHubHelper>();
    }
}
```

HomeController.cs (V1 - works):

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public string Index()
    {
        return "Hello, world!";
    }

}
```

HomeController.cs (V2 - index.cshtml not found):

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you created the view Index for the home controller? replace return view in v 2 with return new EmptyResult(); if it works then for sure you did not created the index view for that particular controller

Comment: I'm not sure whether you mean "the view called Index[.cshtml]" or "the view-index". The file Index.cshtml is in the correct place. I tried EmptyResult() and a blank page appeared (92 B, status 200).

Comment: if it loaded a blank page with return empty result I am sure you don t have an index page for the HomeController. You should have the view like this , the same exact name and also in the same exact folder https://ibb.co/6D8hkRT

Comment: I can't see anything wrong - the file is there: https://ibb.co/72mx3bW

Comment: I just saw that in App.xaml.cs you have a different content root. Try to put .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()) and see if it works. Or debug the path variable and check if is pointing to the correct path.

Comment: Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() and System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location return the same value in this instance.

Answer (score 3):

Found it. Sigh. Through a fairly unrelated Q&A, I used resource monitor to determine that no file opens were even being attempted. That led me to believe the pages should have been compiled - and that led to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54600273/net-core-3-0-preview-2-razor-views-dont-automatically-recompile-on-change) which indicated a breaking change. To quote from one of the answers (credit: Dmitry Pavlov):

1. Reference `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation` (prerelease)
2. Call `services.AddMvc().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation()`

And finally it works. The cshtml file was there all along, as it should have been and knew it was, but it just wasn't getting compiled.