# After updating Visual Studio 2019 to 16.4.0 I can't edit *.cshtml when in debuging

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

After updating Visual Studio 2019 to 16.4.0, I can't edit *.cshtml when in debugging, by any changes I need to stop debugging and again debug.
What shall I do?

Comment: You can try to report a problem on [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [.NET Core 3.0 - Preview 2 - Razor views don't automatically recompile on change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54600273/net-core-3-0-preview-2-razor-views-dont-automatically-recompile-on-change)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a ASP.net core 3.0 project, as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-compilation?view=aspnetcore-3.0) (from [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/698449/changes-to-cshtml-not-taking-effect-in-debug-mode.html)), you have to enable this feature from the code.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddRazorPages()
            .AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
    ...
}
```