# How to fix NuGet package Razor runtime compilation Error?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, .net-core-3.0, .net-core-3.1

After reading through several answers ([.NET Core 3.0 - Preview 2 - Razor views don't automatically recompile on change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54600273/net-core-3-0-preview-2-razor-views-dont-automatically-recompile-on-change)) that recomend installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation NuGet package to get back runtime compilation, I tried the suggested solutions but the project gets the following error message simply by installing the package without even using AddRazorRuntimeCompilation():

The project "project name" must provide a value for configuration

double clicking in the error leads to the following path:

C:\Users....nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.razor.design\2.2.0\build\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design.CodeGeneration.targets

But there is no indication as to what is wrong with this file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `<RazorCompileOnBuild>false</RazorCompileOnBuild>` to your .csproj file. That should allow you to build the project.

You also might need `<MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>false</MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>` for publishing to a server.

See example below:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    ...
    <RazorCompileOnBuild>false</RazorCompileOnBuild>
    <MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>false</MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>
    ...
</PropertyGroup>
```

Found this property from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62622157/88204) on a related question.