# Runtime Error with Deployed ASP.NET Core MVC app; doesn't occur during debugging in VS '19

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, azure-web-app-service

I have an app that I've been building and running in Visual Studio. I've been doing fine, until today when the deployed app suddenly won't load a specific page. When I run the app through VS in debug mode, all is well.

But when I run the app and try to load a specific page, I see the following error in the Application Event Logs:

> ActionName: MapItGo_Web_App.Controllers.ShippingSchedulesController.EditRelayCalendar >(MapItGo Web App)
>
> The view 'EditRelayCalendar' was not found.
> Searched locations:
> /Views/ShippingSchedules/EditRelayCalendar.cshtml,
> /Views/Shared/EditRelayCalendar.cshtml,
> /Pages/Shared/EditRelayCalendar.cshtml

The page exists. And like I said - when I run the app in the debugger, it runs fine. This is totally bizarre to me. It was running completely fine this morning, when I had a colleague testing that particular page out.

This app is being deployed to MS Azure.

Any ideas?

Comment: Don't mean to be snide; however, this points to the fact that something in Azure is not right.  Rely heavily on the error message because it's right 98% of the time, it's simply telling you it cannot find the resources.  If they are there, then perhaps it's an access error.  The issue is in Azure after the deploy.

Answer (score 0):

I had tried with Asp.net core MVC application deployed using Visual Studio 2019. I am not facing any issue like Runtime Error.

Please try to `clear cache` the solution, `rebuild the solution` and try to deploy into azure. If you still have an issue please raise a support ticket [New support request - Microsoft Azure](https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_Azure_Support/HelpAndSupportBlade/overview)

Refer for more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54600273/net-core-3-0-razor-views-dont-automatically-recompile-on-change)